# How to link another user's Adwords account to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have many websites in my Google Analytics. For one of the websites, I have an advertisement manager whose Google account has access to analytics data. Our advertisement manager has made ad campaigns on Google Adwords and now I want to link his Adwords account to the Google Analytics account of mine. I was playing with it for a while but no success. Is it possible to do it? If yes, how!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there's a common email address between the two accounts, you should be able to link them.

In other words, either your Analytics email address should have access to the AdWords account, or your ad manager's AdWords email address should have access to your Analytics account.

If you'd rather not give access to your Analytics account, it'd be simpler to create a new Analytics account specific to this website and share that with your advertisement manager.